# Looking to limit the number of characters on my post page

Tags: the-content

I want my posts to be limited to number characters. I want this to happen on the page that shows all my posts. I am using this snippet.  The read more link also appears when you are viewing the single post. I only want this to happen on the multi post view

[image]
[image]

```
//for index.php that calls content
    add_filter("the_content", "break_text");
    function break_text($text){
    $length = 500;
    if(strlen($text)<$length+10) return $text;//don't cut if too short

    $break_pos = strpos($text, ' ', $length);//find next space after desired length
    $visible = substr($text, 0, $break_pos);
    return balanceTags($visible) . "<a href='".get_permalink()."'>read more</a> ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to do this would be to use `the_excerpt()` instead of `the_content()` in your archive templates, then use this filter the change the number of *words* that appear in the excerpt:

```
function wpse_280633_excerpt_length() {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpse_280633_excerpt_length' );
```

If you want to stick with what you've got and not apply it to single post views, use a combination of `is_main_query()` and `is_singular()` to check if you're in a list of posts or not:

```
function wpse_280633_break_text( $content ) {
    if ( is_main_query() && ! is_singular() ) {
        $length = 500;
        if(strlen($content)<$length+10) return $content;//don't cut if too short

        $break_pos = strpos($content, ' ', $length);//find next space after desired length
        $visible = substr($content, 0, $break_pos);
        $content = balanceTags($visible) . "<a href='".get_permalink()."'>read more</a> ";
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_280633_break_text' );
```

Comment: that worked for the single post view. but now the thumbnail image and excerpt are not showing on the post collection view... I didnt think it would be that hard to limit the amount of characters on a post collections view. are there any other ways?

Comment: Sorry I didn't replace every instance of `$text` with `$content`. I've updated my answer. But the only reason images would be missing is if the image was part of the content. If you added it as a featured image it wouldn't be affected by the `the_content` filter. You should be using my first method though, it's the simplest way to do it. You're making it harder on yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the length of character in following way

```
<?php 
   $str= get_the_excerpt();
   echo $str1= substr ($str,0,50);
?>
```

Please check this and let me know if you are facing any issues.